# Circle to circle collision detection on processing arraylist

Tags: java, processing, collision-detection, collision

I am trying to avoid creating circle on another circle. I can not get the collision detection working. The machine crashes with endless loop.

How can I make sure that the circles don`t collide with each other while creating them?

```java
ArrayList balls;
int maxBall = 10;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 800);
  smooth();
  noStroke();

  // Create an empty ArrayList
  balls = new ArrayList();


  float radius = 100;

  balls.add(new Ball(random(50, width-50), random(50, height-50), radius, color(0, 255, 100) ));

  while (balls.size() < maxBall) { 
    Ball ball = new Ball(random(50, width-50), random(50, height-50), radius, color(0, 255, 100) );


    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
      Ball currentBall = (Ball) balls.get(i);
      float distance = checkCollision(currentBall.getX(), currentBall.getY(), radius, ball.getX(), ball.getY(), radius);
      if (distance > 200) {
        balls.add(ball);
        println("Added, distance: " + distance);
      }
      println();
      //println("Distance: " + distance);

    }
  }
}


void draw() {
  background(0, 0);

  for (int i = balls.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Ball ball = (Ball) balls.get(i);

    ball.display();
  }
}

class Ball {

  float x;
  float y;
  float r;
  color colorID;


  Ball(float tempX, float tempY, float tempW, color tempColor) {
    x = tempX;
    y = tempY;
    r = tempW;
    colorID = tempColor;
  }


  void display()
  {
    fill (colorID);
    ellipse(x, y, r, r);
  }

  float getX() { 
    return x;
  }
  float getY() { 
    return y;
  }
}

float checkCollision(float x1, float y1, float r1, float x2, float y2, float r2) { 
  return dist(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `Math.abs()` in the `checkcirclecollide`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. This might be useful for some body, so I will explain what I have done.

The first problem was the ellipseMode, I set it to:

```
ellipseMode(RADIUS);
```

Secondly, I wasn`t aware of dist function

```
dist(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2);
```

Anyway, the working code:

```
ArrayList balls;
int maxBall = 10;
boolean foundCollision;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 800);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);

  // Create an empty ArrayList
  balls = new ArrayList();


  float radius = 100;

  balls.add(new Ball(random(100, width-100), random(100, height-100), radius, color(0, 255, 100) ));

  int counter = 0;
  while (balls.size() < maxBall) { 
    foundCollision = false;
    Ball ball = new Ball(random(100, width-100), random(100, height-100), radius, color(0, 255, 100) );


    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
      Ball currentBall = (Ball) balls.get(i);
      float distance = checkCollision(currentBall.getX(), currentBall.getY(), radius, ball.getX(), ball.getY(), radius);
      if (distance < 200) {
        foundCollision = true;
        counter = counter+1;
        println("COllision: " + counter);
        break;
      }
      distance = 0;
    }
    if (!foundCollision) {
      balls.add(ball);
    }

  }
  println("Total COllision counter: " + counter);
}


void draw() {
  background(0, 0);

  for (int i = balls.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Ball ball = (Ball) balls.get(i);

    ball.display();
  }
}

class Ball {

  float x;
  float y;
  float r;
  color colorID;


  Ball(float tempX, float tempY, float tempW, color tempColor) {
    x = tempX;
    y = tempY;
    r = tempW;
    colorID = tempColor;
  }


  void display()
  {
    fill (colorID);
    ellipseMode(RADIUS);
    ellipse(x, y, r, r);
  }

  float getX() { 
    return x;
  }
  float getY() { 
    return y;
  }
}

// Check the collision

float checkCollision(float x1, float y1, float r1, float x2, float y2, float r2) { 
  return dist(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make a ton of sense. First you loop through the `ArrayList` and check whether any of them collide. If not, you add another `Ball`, but you don't check whether that new `Ball` collides with anything already in the `ArrayList`.

Instead, you have to check whether the new `Ball` intersects anything already in the `ArrayList`. Something like this:

```
while (maxBall > balls.size()) { 

   Ball ball = new Ball(random(50, width-50), random(50, height-50), 100, color(0, 255, 100) );

   boolean foundCollision = false;

   for (Ball currentBall : balls) {

      isColliding = checkcirclecollide(currentBall.getX(), currentBall.getY(), 100, ball.getX(), ball.getY(), 100);

      if(isColliding){
         foundCollision = true;
      }     
   }

   if(!foundCollision){
      balls.add(ball);
   }
}
```

Also, just use the `dist()` function that comes with Processing:

```
boolean checkcirclecollide(double x1, double y1, float r1, double x2, double y2, float r2) { 
  return dist(x1, y1, x2, y2) < (r1 + r2);
}
```

More info can be found in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/dist_.html).

Comment: I updated the question, it is still not detecting the collision properly

Comment: @emre22 I've edited my answer. Notice that you have to check every other ball, and only add the new ball if it doesn't collide with any of them. Also, make sure you're using `ellipseMode(RADIUS)` so that you draw ellipses from their centers by specifying their radius.